# Could relocation, the passage of time make a psak need to be re-evaluated?

Tags: halacha-theory

After living in one place, then relocated to another place where it is difficult to fulfill a mitzva, could a different psak from a new rav be adopted?

Would it mean the older psak is dissolved and that the new rav's interpretation is just as ok because the situation has changed?

What would be the best internal motivation for asking for the new psak?

Comment: Not knowing what to do is a great reason to ask. Just be sure to provide all the details and background

Comment: You can ask the original Rav if the relocation makes a difference and request permission to use the new local Rav. That way you make sure sure to show kavod to both.

Answer (score 1):

1. The best practice is to stick to one Rabbi and follow him as long as you can. Different Rabbis can contradict each other even in same situation, rendering Mutar Asur and the vice verse.
2. There's a common confusion between a Psak and an advice. A Psak is a general ruling not meant to be changed, an advice is the opposite - it is a practical ruling not to be ported on other situations.
3. Relocating by itself does not change Halakha, but different considerations (prices and availability of Mitzvot, convenience, security, kids Chinuch, Shalom Bait etc) change Halakhic hierarchy and thus Rabbinical rulings.
4. The Gemorah says "משנה מקום משנה מזל" (based on Rosh Hashona 16b) - "relocating changes person's luck". So it does definitely change person's way of serving Hashem, so proper advise on the best way of doing that is very desirable.

Comment: "Relocating by itself does not change Halakha" - Yom Tov Sheni?

Comment: @hehsy and all minhagim! מקום שיצא משם...